# Не работает Splide при выгрузке сайта через хостинг. Локально все работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, css3

[image: Ошибка на скриншоте]

```
<script src="node_modules/@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll/dist/js/splide-extension-auto-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
const splide = new Splide( '.gallery', {
  type   : 'loop',
  drag   : 'free',
  focus  : 'center',
  arrows : false,
  perPage: 3,
  autoWidth: true,
  autoScroll: {
  speed: 1,
  },
} );
splide.mount( window.splide.Extensions );
</script>
```

Comment: А у вас на хостинге есть пака node_modules? Откуда по вашему, должен взятся Splide? Да и вообще, node_modules предназначены для того. что бы из них собрать готовый JS бандл.

Comment: Папка node_modules есть

Comment: Судя по ошибке 404 - ее либо нет, либо не правильный путь указан. Браузер, при запросе файла, по указанному пути, получает ошибку.

Comment: Принято. Спасибо большое